# Best way to give recipient an encrypted symmetric key?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

As it stands, I have written a python3 project to encrypt a file (using AES) and a public/private key system (RSA) to encrypt the AES key.

My current predicament is as follows, what is the best approach to get the encrypted AES key to the recipient ? My program does NOT depend on the medium for sending of the files, rather just the files are securely encrypted. In other words, once a user chooses a public key of the recipient, there is no peer-to-peer communication.

Is naming the file the RSA encrypted AES key a bad idea ?

I dont have extensive knowledge of cryptography as such, so any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2):

If you know the recipient public RSA key you can use [RSA-KEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation) (KEM : Key Encapsulation Mechanism). RSA-KEM for a single recipient with AES-GCM simply as follows;

- **The Sender**;

  1. First generate a `x` in [2..n-1] uniformly randomly, `n` is the RSA modulus.
  2. Use a Key Derivation Function (KDF) on `x`,

  `key= KDF(x)`

  for AES 128,192, or 256-bit depending on your need. Prefer 256.

  3. Encrypt the `x`,

     `c = x^c mod n`
  4. Encrypt the message with AES-GCM generate an `IV` and

  `(IV,ciphertext,tag) = AES-GCM-Enc(IV,message, key)`

  5. Send `(c,(IV,ciphertext,tag))`
- **The receiver**;

  1. To get `x`, They are using their private exponent `d`,

  `x = c^d mod n`

  2. Uses the same (KDF) on `x` to derive same AES key,

  `key= KDF(x)`

  3. Decrypts the message with AES-GCM

  `message = AES-GCM-Dec(IV,ciphertext,tag, key)`

**Note 1:** This is actually a composition of a KEM and a DEM (data encapsulation mechanism; an authenticated cipher serves as a DEM). This provides the standard of IND-CCA2/NM-CCA2—ciphertext indistinguishability and nonmalleability under adaptive chosen-ciphertext attack. That is the minimum requirement for modern Cryptography.

**Note 2:** If you want to send the key itself as you described, to prevent the attacks on textbook RSA, you will need a padding scheme like OAEP or PKCS#v1.5. RSA-KEM eliminates this by using the full modulus as a message.

**Note 3:** The above described RSA-KEM work for a single-user case. RSA-KEM for multiple users will fall into [Håstad's broadcast attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack#H%C3%A5stad's_broadcast_attack). Instead use RSAES-OAEP, this makes it safe for multiple recipients with the same `x` encrypted for different recipients. This will make it very useful to send the message multiple recipients instead of creating a new `x` for every recipient and encrypting the message for each derived key (as PGP/GPG does).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I think i am going to use the OAEP method to send the key